# Start TCPListener on ALL Machine in LAN using Single Application C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I have gone through
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.100).aspx  and have also refereed many article/post on TCPListener .. But i am not able to understand  whether i can start TCP listener from my local machine to all machine connected to my LAN at PORT 8888 using C#?

I have two computer connected in LAN say compA(192.168.1.1) and compB(192.168.1.2). Now I want to start TCPListener on compB from compA. In other word, If i start an application(window C#) in compA, It should start Listener in compB say at(192.168.1.2:888)

Comment: Sam, I am not able to understand your question, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot arbitrarily start a `TcpListener` on another machine, unless you have specific software already installed on that machine for that purpose; being able to do so would be a clear and obvious security problem.

The address/endpoint parameter on `TcpListener` is a **local** address/endpoint. A single machine can have multiple IP addresses, and that parameter simply allows you to bind to a specific one, rather than responding on all bindings.

If you just want other machines to be able to connect to compA, then that is fine and easy: just start the listener on compA, telling it to bind to port 8888, or if you want to be more specific: 192.168.1.1 on port 8888. But that does nothing whatsoever to compB, until such time as compB tries to open a TCP connection to compA.